# sqlite function for removing accentuation from arabic text iOS xcode

Tags: ios, sqlite

Hi i am using sqlite FTS4 and my .sqlite file is in the main Bundle, i implemented this function mentioned here
[How to deal with accented characters in iOS SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356062/how-to-deal-with-accented-characters-in-ios-sqlite/10356596#10356596)

```
void unaccented(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1 || sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) != SQLITE_TEXT) {
        sqlite3_result_null(context);
        return;
    }
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])];
        CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)string, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);
        sqlite3_result_text(context, [string UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
}

- (void)createUnaccentedFunction
{
    if (sqlite3_create_function_v2(euph, "unaccented", 1, SQLITE_ANY, NULL, &unaccented, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_create_function_v2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(euph));
}
```

the following query that i need does not work (query OK but no results),

```
SELECT term_id,eng_term, ara_term, type_id FROM mainporter where unaccented(ara_term) MATCH '%@'
```

But when using an old column that i removed accentuation from manually, i can get results unaccented. so the functions is working fine

```
SELECT term_id,eng_term, unaccented(ara_term), type_id FROM mainporter where ara_term_2 MATCH '%@'
```

Any suggestions ?
Sorry i had to start a new question but i can't comment as i don't have 50+ reputation (thumbs up) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTS matching works only on columns of a FTS table; you cannot apply MATCH to the result of a function.

To remove accents, try the [UNICODE61 tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer), or implement your own [custom tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_1).

Comment: Thank you just two quick questions, can i use UNICODE61 and porter becuase what i understood is that unicode61 is based on the simple tokenizer, and do you know of a good tutorial on how to implement a custom tokenizer, maybe my only  option is a to modify porter to  recognizes arabic accentuation. ?